# Can search bar fixed in navigation bar -bootstrap in mobile view

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-typeahead

I am a web developer and doing a responsive website using bootstrap and wordpress. I have a search bar in the main navigation bar. In the mobile view there comes a toggle button for menu and the search bar will be shown in the dropdown.

My problem is, i would like the search bar to be shown in the main navigation bar  itself, not in dropdown, in mobile view. Is there any solution for this ?
Here is the website url : http://galtechprojects.com/wp_talichka/

Thanks in advance.

Following is my code of navigation part in header.php

```
  <div class="top-bar-inner-left">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar " role="navigation" style="background-color:#000;">
        <div class="container" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="background-color:#000;">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="padding:left-0px;padding-right:0px;">


            <!--START COL MD 9-->
            <div class="col-md-9" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">



        <li class="font"><a href="index.html" class="active">HELLO </a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="fashion.html">FASHION</a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="#">FOOD</a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="#">BEAUTY </a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="#">ART</a></li>

    <li class="font">  <a href="#">PRESS</a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>

    <li class="font"><a href="about.html">CONTACT US</a></li>





                    </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!--START COL MD 3-->
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:1%; overflow:hidden;padding-right:0px;">

                    <div class="bottom_search">

                    <span style="float:left;">


    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="">
        <div style="float: left;width: 100%;margin-top: 2%;"><input type="text" size="18" placeholder="SEARCH" value="" name="s" id="s" class="input" style="float: left" onfocus="clearvalu()"  />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" class="btn1" />
    </div>
    </form>

                    </span>

                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--END COL MD 3-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

    </div>
```

Comment: put search container to be outer from the navbar-collapse class.

Comment: please paste header.php file from your theme

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code, but you could try to add it to the navbar-header.

So, I have to move your form to go inside the navbar-header. I modify a little your search bar, to add the default bootstrap search glyphicon.

```
 <div class="top-bar-inner-left">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" style="background-color:#000;">
        <div class="container" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                style="background-color:#000;"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
                <form method="get" id="searchform" action="" class="navbar">

                    <div style="float: left;width: 100%;margin-top: 8%;" class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" size="18" placeholder="SEARCH" value="" name="s" id="s"
                        class="input" style="float: left" onfocus="clearvalu()">

                        <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                              <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </div>

                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            style="padding:left-0px;padding-right:0px;">
                <!--START COL MD 9-->
                <div class="col-md-9" style="overflow:hidden;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="font"><a href="index.html" class="active">HELLO </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="fashion.html" class="">FASHION</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="#" class="">FOOD</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="#" class="">BEAUTY </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="#" class="">ART</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"> <a href="#" class="">PRESS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="about.html" class="">ABOUT US</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="font"><a href="about.html" class="">CONTACT US</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--START COL MD 3-->
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:1%; overflow:hidden;padding-right:0px;">
                    <div class="bottom_search"> <span style="float:left;" class="">




                    </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--END COL MD 3-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.
Here is a DEMO on bootply:  [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/fJWF6v3PaU)

Comment: the navigation part (code) in the header.php is provided.